# Espaço em branco JSTL

Tags: javascript, java, java-ee, jstl, foreach-jstl

Estou com um problema muito chato, quando meu jsp é montado tenho um foreach em jstl que deixa meu código final absurdamente gigante, pior que percebi que é apenas espaço em branco.
Segue o código :

```
   <c:forEach var="column" items="${tela.targetXml.column}" varStatus="rowStatus" >
        <c:set var="podeAdicionar" value="true" />
        <c:forEach var="col" items="${tela.columns}" varStatus="colTelaStatus" >
            <c:if test="${col.nome == column.name}">
                <c:set var="podeAdicionar" value="false" />
            </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
        <c:if test="${column.visivel && podeAdicionar}">
            div2 = jQuery('<div class="col-md-12" onclick="adicionarColuna(\'${column.name}\', \'${column.label}\', this);event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();">');
            lb = jQuery('<label name="${column.name}">').text('${column.label}');
            div2.append(lb);
            div.append(div2);
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
```

Esse trecho de foreach deixa esse espaço em branco : 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso remover isso, o ideal seria não precisar mimificar o arquivo para evitar erros.

Comment: O que acontece se você colocar `<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>` no começo da página?

Comment: Fui atras dessa configuração depois da sua resposta e consegui resolver no web.xml, obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 3):

Consegui resolver adicionando a seguinte configuração em meu web.xml :

```
  <jsp-config>  
     <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
     </jsp-property-group>
  </jsp-config>
```

Essa configuração removeu em todas as minhas páginas e funcionou tranquilamente.